# Get index of row with qualifying value from a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

I have this array in PHP:

```
array(
    [0] => array( 'username' => 'user1' )
    [1] => array( 'username' => 'user2' )
)
```

If I have the 'username' string how can I get the index value as a number?

Example, if I have 'user1' how can I get 0?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have a 2D array, like in your example, you'll need to customise things a little:

```
function array_search2d($needle, $haystack) {
    for ($i = 0, $l = count($haystack); $i < $l; ++$i) {
        if (in_array($needle, $haystack[$i])) return $i;
    }
    return false;
}

$myArray = array(
    array( 'username' => 'user1' ),
    array( 'username' => 'user2' )
);
$searchTerm = "user1";

if (false !== ($pos = array_search2d($searchTerm, $myArray))) {
    echo $searchTerm . " found at index " . $pos;
} else {
    echo "Could not find " . $searchTerm;
}
```

If you wanted to search in just one particular field, you could alter the function to something like this:

```
function array_search2d_by_field($needle, $haystack, $field) {
    foreach ($haystack as $index => $innerArray) {
        if (isset($innerArray[$field]) && $innerArray[$field] === $needle) {
            return $index;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Instead of looping the array with the for/count loop - why not "foreach($haystack as $key => $value)" - also, this would find 'user1' in any field, not just "username"

Comment: Oh. The OP was a bit ambiguous about that aspect of the problem. I'll edit now.

Answer (score 26):

Take a look at [array_search](http://us.php.net/array_search).

From the PHP help file:

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
?>
```

Comment: this won't work for him, since he has a 2D array. though... it's been accepted, strangely.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I accepted it too soon. Any idea on how to do it with a 2D array?

Comment: @nickf, it actually answers the title of the question, thought it indeed doesn't answer the body of it.

Comment: This answer is incorrect/inappropriate for this asked question.  Its vote tally is only going to mislead/confuse researchers.

Answer (score 7):

Loop through the array and compare the sought value against the specific associative element in each row until a match is found.

As soon as a match is found `return` the row's index to break the loop -- this will provide best efficiency.

If there are no rows that contain the qualifying data, then `false` will be returned.

```
private function getRowKeyByUsername($haystack, $needle)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $row) {
        if ($row['username'] === $needle) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know that the key is `username`, just use an array as the search parameter:

```
$username = 'user1';
$key = array_search(array('username' => $username), $array);
```

Comment: @mickmackusa  And your point?  https://3v4l.org/nmnu5

Comment: Right you are, but I better clarify for future readers.  This answer is most concise and appropriate for the asker's sample data, but if there are more elements in the rows, then it will not work as expected because whole rows of data must be matched (loosely equal). https://3v4l.org/XhKKh

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) and [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) together will help.

Class Based Approach.

```
<?php

class ArraySearch2d {
  static protected $_key;
  static protected $_value;

  static function isMatch($element)
  {
    if (!is_array($element)) return false;
    return $element[self::$_key] == self::$_value;
  }

  static function filter(array $arrayToSearch, $key, $value)
  {
    if (!is_string($key)) throw new Exception("Array Key must be a string");
    self::$_key = $key;
    self::$_value = $value;
    return array_filter($arrayToSearch, 'ArraySearch2d::isMatch');
  }

  // to directly answer your question.
  static function getIndex(array $arrayToSearch, $key, $value)
  {
    $matches = self::filter($arrayToSearch, $key, $value);
    if (!count($matches)) return false;
    $indexes = array_keys($matches);
    return $indexes[0];
  }
}

$array = array("1"=>array('username'=>'user1'), "3"=>array('username'=>'user2'));

$matches = ArraySearch2d::filter($array, 'username', 'user2');
var_dump($matches);

$indexs = array_keys($matches);
var_dump($indexs);

// Demonstrating quick answer:
echo "Key for first 'username'=>'user1' element is: "
     .ArraySearch2d::getIndex($array, 'username', 'user1')."\n";
```

Produces:

```
array(1) {
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(5) "user2"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(3)
}
Key for first 'username'=>'user1' element is: 1
```

Without using classes - this produces the same result:

```
<?php
$field="username";
$value = "user2";

function usernameMatch($element)
{
   global $field, $value;
   if (!is_array($element)) return false; 
   return $element[$field] == $value;
}

function getFirstIndex(array $array)
{
  if (!count($array)) return false;
  $indexes = array_keys($array);
  return $indexes[0];
}

$array = array("1"=>array('username'=>'user1'), "3"=>array('username'=>'user2'));

$matches = array_filter($array, 'usernameMatch');
var_dump($matches);

$indexs = array_keys($matches);
var_dump($indexs);


// Demonstrating quick answer - and why you should probably use the class- 
// you don't want to have to remember these "globals" all the time.
$field = 'username';
$value = 'user1';

echo "Key for first 'username'=>'user1' element is: "
     .getFirstIndex(array_filter($array, 'usernameMatch'));
```

Comment: surely the fact that you need to either implement a Class or use globals means that these aren't great approaches? It's quite possible in a couple of lines of code, if you just use a loop.