# How to check if a specific value exists at a specific key in any subarray of a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array, array-column

I need to search a multidimensional array for a specific value in any of the indexed subarrays.

In other words, I need to check a single column of the multidimensional array for a value.  If the value exists anywhere in the multidimensional array, I would like to return `true` otherwise `false`

```
$my_array = array(    
    0 =>  array(  
        "name"   => "john",  
        "id"    =>  4  
    ),  
    1   =>  array(  
        "name" =>  "mark",  
        "id" => 152  
    ), 
    2   =>  array(  
        "name" =>  "Eduard",  
        "id" => 152  
    )
);
```

I would like to know the fastest and most efficient way to check if the array `$my_array` contains a value with the key "id".  For example, if `id => 152` anywhere in the multidimensional array, I would like `true`.

Comment: How to get the key numbers of the founds ids. e.g. the result will be the `1`,`2` if we search `id = 152`. @mickmackusa, @Rob

Comment: Hi @mickmackusa, Can you please do it for me on the above array? Also is the `array_filter()` is faster to search than the `foreach`? Because i have larger array to search with the same key.

Comment: @manas I assume you want [this](https://3v4l.org/XhoTS)  Please remove all of the other comments that you have littered the page with.  If you want multiple values, just don't return or break https://stackoverflow.com/a/16439674/2943403

Answer (score 86):

Nothing will be faster than a simple loop. You can mix-and-match some array functions to do it, but they'll just be implemented as a loop too.

```
function whatever($array, $key, $val) {
    foreach ($array as $item)
        if (isset($item[$key]) && $item[$key] == $val)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How to get the key numbers of the founds ids. e.g. the result will be the `1`,`2` if we search `id = 152`.  @Dan Grossman

Answer (score 38):

The simplest way is this:

```
$my_array = array(    
    0 =>  array(  
        "name"   => "john",  
        "id"    =>  4  
    ),  
    1   =>  array(  
        "name" =>  "mark",  
        "id" => 152  
    ), 
    2   =>  array(  
        "name" =>  "Eduard",  
        "id" => 152  
    )
);

if (array_search(152, array_column($my_array, 'id')) !== FALSE) {
  echo 'FOUND!';
} else {
  echo 'NOT FOUND!';
}
```

Comment: How to get the key values (1 and 2) of the searched id(152) value?

Answer (score 34):

** PHP >= 5.5

simply u can use this

```
$key = array_search(40489, array_column($userdb, 'uid'));
```

Let's suppose this multi dimensional array:

```
$userdb=Array
(
(0) => Array
    (
        (uid) => '100',
        (name) => 'Sandra Shush',
        (url) => 'urlof100'
    ),

(1) => Array
    (
        (uid) => '5465',
        (name) => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
        (pic_square) => 'urlof100'
    ),

(2) => Array
    (
        (uid) => '40489',
        (name) => 'Michael',
        (pic_square) => 'urlof40489'
    )
);

$key = array_search(40489, array_column($userdb, 'uid'));
```

Comment: Why not simply `$ids = array_column($array, 'id', 'id');` and then `isset($ids[40489])`?

Comment: Hey, do yo mind updating your answer and implement the comment from Elias?

Comment: It is important to clarify for future researchers that `$key` may be `0` which is a falsey value.  To know if `array_search()` found qualifying data, you must explicitly check if `$key !== false` or `$key === false` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 25):

Here is an updated version of Dan Grossman's answer which will cater for multidimensional arrays (what I was after):

```
function find_key_value($array, $key, $val)
{
    foreach ($array as $item)
    {
        if (is_array($item) && find_key_value($item, $key, $val)) return true;

        if (isset($item[$key]) && $item[$key] == $val) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this, but without checking for a specific value? Return true if the key is empty, return false if the key is not empty.

Comment: What if you don't have the actual value of $key to pass in? I want to search my entire array regardless of what the key is.

Comment: Sounds like you simply need the php function 'array_search'

Comment: Because the input data is limited to a depth of 2 levels, it is unnecessary overhead to implement a recursive technique for this task.  If this was a recursive task (and it isn't) then `array_walk_recursive()` would visit only the leaf nodes and eliminate the `is_array()` check.

Comment: My array had a lot more levels than 2 

Answer (score 8):

If you have to make a lot of "id" lookups and it should be really fast you should use a second array containing all the "ids" as keys:

```
$lookup_array=array();

foreach($my_array as $arr){
    $lookup_array[$arr['id']]=1;
}
```

Now you can check for an existing id very fast, for example:

```
echo (isset($lookup_array[152]))?'yes':'no';
```

Answer (score 6):

A good solution can be one provided by `@Elias Van Ootegan` in a comment that is:

```
$ids = array_column($array, 'id', 'id');
echo isset($ids[40489])?"Exist":"Not Exist";
```

I tried it and worked for me, thanks buddy.

**Edited**

Note: It will work in PHP 5.5+

Comment: Note that `array_column` requires PHP 5.5+ - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 4):

[TMTOWTDI](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TMTOWTDI). Here are several solutions in order of complexity.

(Short primer on complexity follows):`O(n)` or "big o" means **worst** case scenario where `n` means the number of elements in the array, and `o(n)` or "little o" means **best** case scenario. Long discrete math story short, you **only really have to worry about the worst case scenario**, and make sure it's not `n ^ 2` or `n!`. It's more a measure of change in computing time as `n` increases than it is overall computing time. [Wikipedia has a good article about computational aka time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity).

If experience has taught me anything, it's that spending too much time optimizing your programs' little-o is a distinct waste of time better spent doing something - anything - better.

#### Solution 0: `O(n) / o(1)` complexity:

This solution has a best case scenario of 1 comparison - 1 iteration thru the loop, but **only provided the matching value is in position 0 of the array**. The worst case scenario is it's not in the array, and thus has to iterate over every element of the array.

```
foreach ($my_array as $sub_array) {
    if (@$sub_array['id'] === 152) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

#### Solution 1: `O(n) / o(n)` complexity:

This solution must loop thru the entire array no matter where the matching value is, so it's always going to be `n` iterations thru the array.

```
return 0 < count(
    array_filter(
        $my_array,
        function ($a) {
            return array_key_exists('id', $a) && $a['id'] == 152;
        }
    )
);
```

#### Solution 2: `O(n log n) / o(n log n)` complexity:

A hash insertion is where the `log n` comes from; `n` hash insertions = `n * log n`. There's a hash lookup at the end which is another `log n` but it's not included because that's just how discrete math works.

```
$existence_hash = [];
foreach ($my_array as $sub_array) {
    $existence_hash[$sub_array['id']] = true;
}
return @$existence_hash['152'];
```

Comment: Casting `array_filter()`'s return value as `(bool)` will spare you having to count the results or compare against `0`.  https://3v4l.org/2dVAu  For anyone who is looking for the most efficient technique (and the OP is), using `array_filter()` will  continue to iterate the input array even after a match is found so this will not be best way.

Comment: [The `count()` call is an `O(1)` operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566314/php-what-is-the-complexity-i-e-o1-on-of-the-function-count), so there's no optimization by using a cast. Even if you write it as a short-circuiting `for` loop, the worst-case scenario would still be `O(n)` since the ID could not exist in `$my_array`.

Comment: By converting to `(bool)` there is no function call and no conditional comparison on `array_filter()`'s return value so it is more direct and concise to convert to boolean type.  DanGrossman's technique (though I'd be using curly braces for all language constructs) is going to be the best performer because it executes a conditional early return/break.  I am sure you already know this; I am only stating this fact for researchers.  Please add an explanation to your answer to role model better posting behaviors to newer users.

Answer (score 2):

I came upon this post looking to do the same and came up with my own solution I wanted to offer for future visitors of this page (and to see if doing this way presents any problems I had not forseen).

If you want to get a simple `true` or `false` output and want to do this with one line of code without a function or a loop you could serialize the array and then use `stripos` to search for the value:

`stripos(serialize($my_array),$needle)`

It seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

As in your question, which is actually a simple 2-D array wouldn't it be better? Have a look-

Let say your 2-D array name $my_array and value to find is $id

```
function idExists($needle='', $haystack=array()){
    //now go through each internal array
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if ($item['id']===$needle) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and to call it:

```
idExists($id, $my_array);
```

As you can see, it actually only check if any internal index with key_name 'id' only, have your $value. Some other answers here might also result true if key_name 'name' also has $value

Comment: This one is going to be one of the best performers on the page because it employs an early return and doesn't create a temporary array of `id` column data before checking for the needle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with only two parameter

```
function whatever($array, $val) {
    foreach ($array as $item)
        if (isset($item) && in_array($val,$item))
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `isset($item)` doesn't make a lot of sense in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is better or worse for performance, but here is an alternative:

```
$keys = array_map(function($element){return $element['id'];}, $my_array);
$flipped_keys = array_flip($keys);
if(isset($flipped_keys[40489]))
{
    // true
}
```

Comment: you might also be interested in array_column https://php.net/array_column

Comment: I saw, many have suggested it and I had tried it alone and couldn't get it to work until I saw Manuel's above. `$key = array_search(40489, array_column($userdb, 'uid'));`. I had already found my solution and just thought I'd share it. The array_search and array_column combo works perfect though.

Comment: array_column and array_flip works equally. it was merely meant as a hint FYI, the array_map part can be replaced by it, the rest would be the same. Personally I would not combine it with array_search,but more like you did with array_flip.

Answer (score 0):

different between **isset vs array_key_exits**
[What's the difference between isset() and array_key_exists()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210935/whats-the-difference-between-isset-and-array-key-exists/3210982)

different between **== vs ===** [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp)

```
function specificValue(array $array,$key,$val) {
    foreach ($array as $item)
        if (array_key_exits($item[$key]) && $item[$key] === $val)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This answer does not work for multiple reasons.  Please test your code before posting.

Answer (score 0):

`array_column` returns the values of a single column of an array and we can search for a specific value for those via `in_array`

```
if (in_array(152, array_column($my_array, 'id'))) {
    echo 'FOUND!';
} else {
    echo 'NOT FOUND!';
}
```

Comment: `in_array()` is one of the least efficient ways to perform an array search.  [@ImranQamer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41500450/2943403) will perform better because it searches keys instead of values.  This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a queue of sub-arrays and loop each:

```
function existsKeyValue($myArray, $key, $value) {
    $queue = [$myArray]; //creating a queue of a single element, which is our outermost array

    //when we reach the count of the queue we looped all inner loops as well and failed to find the item
    for ($index = 0; $index < count($queue); $index++) {
        //Looping the current array, finding the key and the value
        foreach ($queue[$index] as $k => &$v) {
            //If they match the search, then we can return true
            if (($key === $k) && ($value === $v)) {
                return true;
            }
            //We need to make sure we did not already loop our current array to avoid infinite cycles
            if (is_array($v)) $queue[]=$v;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$my_array = array(    
    0 =>  array(  
        "name"   => "john",  
        "id"    =>  4  
    ),  
    1   =>  array(  
        "name" =>  "mark",  
        "id" => 152  
    ), 
    2   =>  array(  
        "name" =>  "Eduard",  
        "id" => 152  
    )
);

echo var_dump(existsKeyValue($my_array, 'id', 152));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `array_column` as in below example:

```
$my_array = [
    [
        "name"  => "john",  
        "id"    =>  4  
    ],  
    [
        "name"  =>  "mark",  
        "id"    => 152  
    ], 
    [
        "name"  =>  "Eduard",  
        "id"    => 152  
    ]
];
var_dump(in_array(152, array_column($my_array, 'id'))); // true
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this below code. It should be working fine for any kind of multidimensional array search.

Here you can see [LIVE DEMO EXAMPLE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5307cbf8266ae9a3f23e59da653148997df78cde)

```
function multi_array_search($search_for, $search_in) {
    foreach ($search_in as $element) {
        if ( ($element === $search_for) ){
            return true;
        }elseif(is_array($element)){
            $result = multi_array_search($search_for, $element);
            if($result == true)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Notice how using recursion is not only needless overhead, it is doing unnecessary checks on first level elements.  Proof that recursion is a bad choice for this question.  https://3v4l.org/Aua2W

Answer (score -1):

```
function checkMultiArrayValue($array) {
        global $test;
        foreach ($array as $key => $item) {

            if(!empty($item) && is_array($item)) {
                checkMultiArrayValue($item);
            }else {
                if($item)
                 $test[$key] = $item;

            }
        }
        return $test;   
    }

 $multiArray = array(    
                0 =>  array(  
                      "country"   => "",  
                      "price"    => 4,  
                      "discount-price" => 0,  
               ),);

$test = checkMultiArrayValue($multiArray);
echo "<pre>"
print_r($test);
```

Will return array who have index and value

Comment: This task does not benefit from a recursive technique.  This code-only answer will do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.  When you post an answer always explain in plain English how it works and what advantages it has over other answers to this specific question.

Answer (score -3):

I wrote the following function in order to determine if an multidimensional array partially contains a certain value.

```
function findKeyValue ($array, $needle, $value, $found = false){
    foreach ($array as $key => $item){
        // Navigate through the array completely.
        if (is_array($item)){
            $found = $this->findKeyValue($item, $needle, $value, $found);
        }

        // If the item is a node, verify if the value of the node contains
        // the given search parameter. E.G.: 'value' <=> 'This contains the value'
        if ( ! empty($key) && $key == $needle && strpos($item, $value) !== false){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return $found;
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
$this->findKeyValue($array, $key, $value);
```

Comment: There is no reason to use recursion for this task. The input array is just two levels deep.  This is unnecessary convolution that should not be used for this problem.