# PHP manipulating multidimensional array values by key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have tried the following:

```
$tree['uid1']['page'] = "page1";
$tree['uid1']['childs']['uid2']['page'] = "page2";
$tree['uid1']['childs']['uid3']['page'] = "page3";

array_walk_recursive($tree, function (&$item, $key) {
  echo $key.', ';
  if ($key == 'uid3') {
    // push array('childs' => array('uid4' => array('page' => 'page4')))
  }
});
```

But echo $key.', '; only returns me the last key ("page")
Have I done something wrong or have I misunderstood the function "array_walk_recursive"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the first comment [at the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) you will realice it doesn't work as you expected:

> - THIS FUNCTION ONLY VISITS LEAF NODES *
>
> That is to say that if you have a tree of arrays with subarrays of
>   subarrays, only the plain values at the leaves of the tree will be
>   visited by the callback function.  The callback function isn't ever
>   called for a nodes in the tree that subnodes (i.e., a subarray).  This
>   has the effect as to make this function unusable for most practical
>   situations.

If you want to check whether a key exist in your array or not, you might want to take a look at [this solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990855/php-check-if-value-and-key-exist-in-multidimensional-array).

Comment: I was about to quote the exact same thing :p +1