# Find if a value exits in the multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to find if a value exists in a multidimensional array?

```
$comments_array = array();

$comments_array[] = array(
               "comment" => "comment1", 
               "flag_user_id" => "1",
                user_id => "2", 
               "username" => "Xylon",
               "comment_id" => "3"
         );

$comments_array[] = array(
               "comment" => "comment2", 
               "flag_user_id" => "4", 
               user_id => "2", 
               "username" => "Xylon", 
               "comment_id" => "6"
             );
```

In the above given array, I want to find if comment2 exits and retrieve it's falg_user_id

Comment: you go with a loop for each of them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990855/php-check-if-value-and-key-exist-in-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that I worked out for your question.

```
foreach ($comments_array as $arr) {
    if (array_key_exists('comment', $arr) && $arr['comment'] == 'comment2') {
        if (array_key_exists('flag_user_id', $arr)) {
            return $arr['flag_user_id'];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

`array_key_exists()` is a PHP method that returns `true` or `false` based on if a specified key exists in an array. I simply loop through all sub arrays of your multidimensional array, check if the `comments` index exists and if it is equal to your specified `comment2`. If that case is reached, it checks that the `flag_user_id` index exists and returns it's contents. Otherwise this loop defaults to `NULL`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In PHP5.5:

```
$allComments = array_column($comments_array, 'comment');
$key = array_search('comment2', $allComments);
if($key !== false) {
    $flagUserId = $comments_array[$key]['flag_user_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$comment_exists = false;

foreach($comments_array as $arr)
{
    if($arr['comment']=='comment2')
    {
          $comment_exists = true;
    }
}

if($comment_exists)
{
     ehco "exists";
}
else
{
     ehco "not exists";
}
```

Comment: put some explanation to the code posted, this will help other to understand it quickly.