# PHP Fastest way to check if a value in the array exists

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
array [▼
      0 => array:5 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "user_id" => 15
        "parent_campaign_id" => 69464
        "child_campaign_id" => 69464
        "cpm" => "1.00"
      ]
      1 => array:5 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "user_id" => 15
        "parent_campaign_id" => 69464
        "child_campaign_id" => 396331
        "cpm" => "2.00"
      ]
      2 => array:5 [▼
        "id" => 3
        "user_id" => 15
        "parent_campaign_id" => 69464
        "child_campaign_id" => 398032
        "cpm" => "3.00"
      ]
    ]
```

How can I know if a number `396331` exists in that array and the key should be `child_campaign_id`.

I tried `in_array()` but it seems it is not working correctly since the `keys` of this array is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Check if value and key exist in multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990855/php-check-if-value-and-key-exist-in-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple and clean version uses [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter).

```
$filtered = array_filter($original, function($element) {
    return $element['child_campaign_id'] === 396331;
});

if (count($filtered)) {
    // it exists
} else {
    // it doesn't
}
```

It is, of course, possible to use a variable as the search key if you wish:

```
$search = 396331; // or whatever
$filtered = array_filter($original, function($element) use ($search) {
    return $element['child_campaign_id'] === $search;
});
```

Note that the downside of this is that it searches through the entire array, reduces it and then checks to see if there is anything left. A more efficient way, if you have a very large array, would be to loop through and `break;` when you reach the first matching array element.

Comment: What is the `$original` variable there?

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower Your array.

Comment: @cale_b of course it does support variables: `$fn = function($element) use ($id, $val) {return $element[$id] === $val;}; $filtered = array_filter($original, $fn);` What it does not support is multi-dimentional arrays with D > 2, but it is out of scope.

Comment: @cale_b There's a big shiny "edit" button if you want to improve the answer! But I have updated to take your useful points into account.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it will print array index, it will give false result if value is not exist.

```
$index_array= array_search(396331, array_column($array, "child_campaign_id"));
var_dump($index_array);
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/689278)**

Comment: Note that you can also play with the third parameter of `array_column`, this way you don't have to search the array: `isset(array_column($arr, 'id', 'child_campaign_id')[398032])` (or using `key_exists`)