# How to check if value exists in multidimensional array with keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$array = array(
   array('name' => 'number1', 'number' => '0612345675'),
   array('name' => 'number2', 'number' => '0634345675'),
   array('name' => 'number3', 'number' => '0634378675')
);
```

Now I have this number: `0634345675`.
How can I check If this number exists in the array `$array`?

I tried to do this:

```
if(!in_array('0634345675', $array)){
   // insert into DB
}
```

But this keeps adding multiple of the same rows.
Does anyone knows how to check if this number exists in `$array`?

Full code:

```
foreach($DN as $number){ // $DN got ['0634345675', '0632545675', '0614342375']
    if(!in_array($number, $array)){
       // insert into DB
    }
}
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29233744/5209435) looks like what you want, or at least can be adapted very easily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `in_array()` along with `array_column()`

```
<?php

$array = array(
   array('name' => 'number1', 'number' => '0612345675'),
   array('name' => 'number2', 'number' => '0634345675'),
   array('name' => 'number3', 'number' => '0634378675')
);

$valueToFind = '0634345675';

if (in_array($valueToFind, array_column($array, 'number'))){
    echo 'found';
}else{
    echo 'not found';
}
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/TUtSL

***If you want to show that array too,*** then use `array_search()`

```
$key = array_search($valueToFind, array_column($array, 'number'));
if($key){
    echo 'value found';
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo "matched array is";
    echo PHP_EOL;
    print_r($array[$key]);
}
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/Mc2cC

***In case multiple match found:***

```
$valueToFind = '0634378675';

$matchedArray = array();
foreach($array as $arr){
    if($valueToFind == $arr['number']){
        $matchedArray[] = $arr;
    }
}

if( count($matchedArray) > 0){
    echo "match found";
    echo PHP_EOL;
    print_r($matchedArray);
}
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/p439T